# Stack difference between VirtualBox and Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, virtualbox, hyper-v

Let say I want run Linux application on Windows laptop. (Let say the application is Mongo and it MUST be Linux Mongo). I have 2 options

1. I can use VirtualBox to run Linux virtual machine with application
2. I can use Docker for Windows to run Linux docker image with application

My question is: which solution is expected to have better performance? VirtualBox virtual machine has well known overhead, docker instance is a process with low overhead. But between laptop Windows and docker instance AFAIU Docker for Windows establish intermediate virtual machine with Linux (Hyper-V VM?)

Stack looks similar for both options. Could I say that some option has definitely better performance/resource requirements or it depends on specific details?

Comment: From local development perspective this somewhat becomes opinion based. Docker for windows also run a Small VM in Hyper-v and then runs docker inside the same. But Docker for windows may have some better integration when it comes to path mappings and volume mounting. For VM you will have to do this manually yourself

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest use Docker instead of VirtualBox.

- Docker is like independent platform, in future if you want to run on Mac, Linux or windows you just need to copy few files from one place to other to get it set up everything but with VirtualBox you need to copy whole image or re-configured everything.
- Docker provides built-in support for all kind of base images, which will help you to get speedy development.
- With the Docker, you can destroy or re-run image with few/one command.
- Docker provides an easy way to map local folders with VirtualBox you need to configure that.
- VirtualBox is heavy as compared with Docker.
- In Docker, you will always get the fresh/clean environment if you decide to use Continuous Deployment.
- Network mapping (port externalise) and many more things are easily available with Docker.
- Again lastly Go with Docker :)

Hope this get you clear idea, Please let me know if you need any help to setup Docker environment for your development.

Comment: Good point that regardless stack difference, docker offers more flexibility. Anyway, I will - for few days - keep question open. I will still interested in stack details